# How to make my native query faster using indexing in Spring Data Jpa and postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, indexing, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to search a join table of millions of records using JPA native query and PostgreSQL but the result is too slow. I want to make it faster using index search on postgres or any better option that can be suggested. I looked up several articles online like this:
https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index

but am not quite sure how to implement it as am not getting the improved speed.

Here is what I had in my JPA repository:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT C.APPROVED_NAME AS companyName, C.CITY AS city, C.STATE AS state, 
FROM TABLE_NAME_1 C LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME_2 AS A ON A.COMPANY_FK = C.ID 
WHERE CONCAT(UPPER(A.FIRSTNAME), ' ', UPPER(A.SURNAME))
 LIKE UPPER(concat(:searchTerm,'%')) ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<table_1_Interface> findByName(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);
```

Here is what I tried to do using index search (I am new to using index search):

```
 @Query(value = "CREATE INDEX company_search_idx ON TABLE_NAME_2(firstname, surname );
SELECT DISTINCT C.APPROVED_NAME AS companyName, C.CITY AS city, C.STATE AS state, 
FROM TABLE_NAME_1 C LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME_2 AS A ON A.COMPANY_FK = C.ID 
WHERE CONCAT(UPPER(A.FIRSTNAME), ' ', UPPER(A.SURNAME))
 LIKE UPPER(concat(:searchTerm,'%')) ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<table_1_Interface> findByName(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);
```

Please help me with your suggestions, ideas and solutions.

Comment: Did you add foreign key constraint at db level

Comment: Both tables in the join have foreign key relationship. So on the db that foreign key contraint is available. But I did not add any foreign key constraint when trying to perform this indexing.

Comment: Does the same query perform better only at DB side? I mean if you don't execute it by Java.

Comment: No it doesn't... it as slow as without create index @sigur

Comment: What I mean is whether on tables creation is foreignkey constraint created @kingified

Comment: You can use partition table option in postgresql to create tables . It is a considerable speed solution for accessing millions of records in big data .

Comment: yes, on table's creation, foreign key constraint is created. @Gopi krishna

Answer (score 0):

If you search on `CONCAT(UPPER(A.FIRSTNAME), ' ', UPPER(A.SURNAME))` then that is what the index needs to be built on (but without the table aliases).  But for pg_trgm it supports ILIKE directly, so you could just use that instead of manually fiddling with case.

Since you only add a % to the end of the search term, you could instead use a btree index with text_pattern_ops.  But then you would need the UPPER with LIKE.

Comment: but using ILIKE is slow according to https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index

Comment: I don't see that claim being made at that link.  And if it is, then it is wrong, at least in regards to pg_trgm.